# Transform user access dataframe in user access matrix in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, tuples

I have a dataFrame like this:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({
'users': [
    [('007', "us1", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 4)],
    [('008', "us1", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 5)],
    [('009', "us1", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 6)],
    [('007', 'us2', "us3", "time1", 'time2', 4)],
    [('008', 'us2', "us3", "time1", 'time2', 7)], 
    [('009', 'us2', "us3", "time1", 'time2', 11)], 
    [('001', 'us5', 'us1', "time1", 'time2', 0)], 
    [('008', 'us5', 'us1', "time1", 'time2', 1)], 
    [('007',"us3", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 2)],
    [('007',"us3", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 34)],
    [('009',"us3", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 67)]]
  })
```

[image]

A tuple is (ID, user1, user2, timeAcess User1, timeAcess User2, delay), and I want as result the users on a matrix with the list of ID's accessed, like this:

[image]

Also I just want to add on the list on the matrix the Id's that are inside a certain `delayTime` (the last part of the tuple that is numeric). So, for example, if I decide that `delayTime` should be bigger than 7, the Id's that are less than 7 won't be added to the matrix.

I could extract the list of accessed Id's per user tuple:

```
d = d.groupby(d['users'].str[1:3], sort=False)['users'].apply(list).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()
d['IDsAcess'] = d['users'].apply(lambda x: [y[0] for y in x])
```

For after this I am blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
... 'users': [
...     [('007', "us1", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 4)],
...     [('008', "us1", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 5)],
...     [('009', "us1", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 6)],
...     [('007', 'us2', "us3", "time1", 'time2', 4)],
...     [('008', 'us2', "us3", "time1", 'time2', 7)], 
...     [('009', 'us2', "us3", "time1", 'time2', 11)], 
...     [('001', 'us5', 'us1', "time1", 'time2', 0)], 
...     [('008', 'us5', 'us1', "time1", 'time2', 1)], 
...     [('007',"us3", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 2)],
...     [('007',"us3", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 34)],
...     [('009',"us3", "us2", "time1", 'time2', 67)]]
...   })
>>> df =(pd.DataFrame(df["users"].explode().tolist(),columns=["ID","USER1","USER2","TAU1","TAU2","DELAY"])
.groupby(["USER1","USER2"])["ID"].agg(list).to_frame().unstack())
    >>> df
                   ID                                  
    USER2         us1              us2              us3
    USER1                                              
    us1           NaN  [007, 008, 009]              NaN
    us2           NaN              NaN  [007, 008, 009]
    us3           NaN  [007, 007, 009]              NaN
    us5    [001, 008]              NaN              NaN
```

Then you can flatten ID level, add a new us5 column,and fill NaNs with empty list

**EDIT**

If you don't want certain entries to make the list, you can drop rows which are lesser(or greater) than your preferred value before `groupby`

**EDIT2**

```
>>> df =(pd.DataFrame(df["users"].explode().tolist(),columns=["ID","USER1","USER2","TAU1","TAU2","DELAY"])
... .groupby(["USER1","USER2"])["ID"].agg(list).to_frame().unstack())
>>> df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(1)
>>> combined = df.index|df.columns
>>> for col in combined:
...     if col not in df.columns:
...         df[col] = np.nan
>>> df
USER2         us1              us2              us3  us5
USER1                                                   
us1           NaN  [007, 008, 009]              NaN  NaN
us2           NaN              NaN  [007, 008, 009]  NaN
us3           NaN  [007, 007, 009]              NaN  NaN
us5    [001, 008]              NaN              NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering but I could not get it, i have more users than just 4 as in this example, so I can't add by hand the users. Moreover, I could not get the fact of adding us5, it depends on the data that will be the input, this one was an example. Can you answer in a more general way? Thank you again!

Comment: Here us5 didn't appear because there was no us5 value in the "USER2" column. If it were there, us5 column would've appeared automatically

Comment: Yes, that's why I've asked if you could help me to do in a general way, otherwise do not reply correctly to my question... :(

Comment: In addition, I've tried to flatten with reset_index, as you suggested, and the result is not the expected. Could you explain this better? Thanks again

Comment: Updated the answer. You should try to take it up from here

Comment: Thank you, I will!! :)  Just for me to understand the dynamic in StackOverflow, if someone arrives with the same question as I did, and this person checks your answer and it's not complete, this should be ok according to the methodology of answering of StackOverflow? I can add my answer completely after I finish it, but it's more a philosophical question about the website, if we should reply all on the answer or let people to finish by themselves.

Comment: Well, personally, I believe that understanding the direction of the solution is more important than the solution itself. People seeking answers on SO are usually happy to get past their initial stumbling block. But, I get what you're saying. Good luck :)